# Best solution to capture all requests/responses of Asp.Net Web API hosted on Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, logging, azure-application-insights

My system is an Asp.Net Web API (.Net 5) hosted on Azure kubernetes service. I have a requirement to log all requests/responses for all controllers of the system. Currently, the system logs only exceptions to Application Insights using Middleware and the default logger injected by the framework.

My questions are:

1. Should I develop the new requirement as the current implementation
   of logging exceptions by adding an additional middleware to log all
   requests/responses to Application Insights?
2. Are there any services/configurations on Azure to log all requests/responses so
   that I don't need to modify the code?
3. What are the best practices for that kind of requirement? Is this ok to save all
   requests/responses into Application Insights to easily
   query/trace/investigate issues later or it should be somewhere else such as databases. etc.?

Comment: How did you configure application insights? It should track requests and dependencies out of the box.

Comment: I just turned application insights on and leave all the configurations as default. I see it tracks request URL, response code, and response time... but I want to track the request and response body and I may have to modify the log details with a custom format too.

Comment: *I just turned application insights on* Did you install the SDK?  To modify or add request telemetry properties you can use a [telemetry initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer)

Comment: Yes, I installed the Application Insights SDK but I don't use any custom telemetry initializer. What I do for logging exceptions is to use the injected logger and call _logger.LogError in the middleware. So, by using a custom telemetry initializer, I do not need to create an additional middleware for capturing request/response body?

Comment: *So, by using a custom telemetry initializer, I do not need to create an additional middleware for capturing request/response body?* Correct, though I wouldn't store the request and responsen in AI but rather in a storage account due to the possible size. You can correlate them using the telemetry id or request id.